# lldb error Xcode c++

Tags: c++, xcode

```
int xint(int a, int b, int c){

double xintercept;

int cc = -c;

xintercept = cc/a;

return xintercept;

}
int yint(int a, int b, int c){

double yintercept;

int cc = -c;

//this line// yintercept = cc/a;

return yintercept;
}
```

That line is highlighted in green. I have the same code previously(on the 3rd line) and it does not have any problems running

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong here. The declaration of

```
`int cc = -c;`
```

means you're declaring a variable to a non-existing **variable(-c)** and that will give an error. Try to change it to the variable defined, which is **c** and it should get rid of the error.

**P.S:** A function like

```
`xintercept = cc/a;`
```

is **NOT** defined in your 2nd function. You should create a function for **`yintercept`**, because otherwise this is declared but not used.